Issue with Date Handling in Node.js and MySQL: Date Reduced by One Day
I'm experiencing an issue with date handling in my Node.js and MySQL application where the date stored in the database is correct, but when retrieved via an API, it is reduced by one day. Here are the details:
Backend:
I am using Express.js to handle API requests for storing and retrieving event data from a MySQL database:
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const db = req.app.get("db");
  const sql = "SELECT * FROM resource_utilization";
  db.query(sql, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.json(err);
    }
    return res.json(data);
  });
});

When I store an event with a start date of "2024-07-24" in the database, it is stored correctly.
However, when I retrieve this event using the API, the date appears as "2024-07-23".
enter image description here
enter image description here
How can I ensure that the date stored in the database is correctly retrieved via the API without being off by one day? Any insights or suggestions on how to handle date conversions correctly in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Handle timezone correctly , output date is getting converted from local timezone to UTC.

To expand on @Jack's comment: the mysql screenshot shows only date being stored. In the returned output, however, you can see a timestamp (both date and time), not just a date. This indicates timezone difference. As mysql does not apply timezones to a date value, this is done in node.js.
